# what is the necessary and sufficient condition $f^{g(x)}(x)$ to be differentiable at $x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ and $g$ are real functions

**1.** can you give me a counter example to the statement

"if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions then $f^{g(x)}(x)$ is differentiable"

**2.**  what is the necessary and sufficient condition $f^{g(x)}(x)$ to be differentiable at $x$

thanks.

Comment: If $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 1/2$, then $f^g(x) = \sqrt x$ which is not differentiable at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f^{g(x)} (x)$ is not well defined if $f$ takes negative values. So assume that $f$ is non-negative. Then $f^{g(x)} (x)$ at a point $x_0$  iff $f(x_0)>0$ . It is differentiable at all points iff $f(x)>0$ for all $x$. To prove these statements simply write $f^{g(x)} (x)$  as $e^{g(x) \ln f(x)}$.